# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, rest

I access my web in javascript code in SharePoint 2013.
I'm using Jquery and KnockOutJS for my other functions. So I have added following urls above my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

At below line I get an exception says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext("http://myServer:1000/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `sp.js` is not yet loaded when `SP.ClientContext` is being called.

Use [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) to ensure that the specified file that contains the specified function is loaded and then runs the specified callback function.

You could try to enclose your code like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

     var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
     var context = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
     //...

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Pattern

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(FunctionToRunWhenLoadIsFinished, "sp.js"); });



function FunctionToRunWhenLoadIsFinished() {

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ITSTotalDashboard_logs');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'test');


    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I am using WorkflowServices. It should work in your case as well:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('SP.WorkflowServices.js'));
        SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager'], function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
            var instanceService = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
        });
    }, "sp.js");
}, "sp.runtime.js");
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer as [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92082/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-current-of-undefined/191977#191977) Try to be more specific. Thank you